Problem with Displaying the FLOAT numbers in SNMP MIB file
I am New to SNMP and trying to create a .MIB file for my SNMP manager.
I use "iReasoning" on my PC as SNMP Manager.
I can get and observe all the integer values ​​correctly, but I can't display the float numbers!
After searching, I found out that the agent can only send integer values and it should be specified on the Manager's side that the results should be displayed with the number of decimals. So I came up with this code for the .MIB file:
myMIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
        internet            FROM RFC1155-SMI
        OBJECT-TYPE         FROM SNMPv2-SMI
        TEXTUAL-CONVENTION  FROM SNMPv2-TC;
    

-- ---------------------------------------------------------- --
-- Textual Conventions
-- ---------------------------------------------------------- --
Thousandths ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    DISPLAY-HINT    "d-3"
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION     "An integer to be displayed with 3 decimal places;
                     i.e. 12345 displayed as 12.345"
    SYNTAX      INTEGER (-10000..10000)

baseDir     OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { internet 3}
myOID       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { baseDir 1 }


myDeviceVoltage OBJECT-TYPE
            SYNTAX  Thousandths (0..65535)
            UNITS "V"
            ACCESS  read-only
            STATUS  current
            DESCRIPTION
            "Voltage of my Device"
            ::= { myOID Monitoring(1) 1 }
END

But still, the value of the number in "iReasoning" is displayed as an integer!
Any Solution?

Float numbers are just aliens in the SNMP world, so expecting the tools to work in your way isn't feasible.

Dear Lex Li, Thank you for your reply. You are right and I know this.
My SNMP agent measure floating volage value (for Ex. 12.345). But send an INT value (: 12345). After searching I found than there is a way for display integer values as float numbers in SNMP Manager MIB file:
link
But it not works for me!
